# Pocketsphinx android onEndOfSpeech() is called even if i am speaking

Tags: pocketsphinx-android

I am trying to recognize numbers in the app. when I am speaking numbers it calls `onEndOfSpeech()` method but I still have to speak the number. Sometimes it works fine and sometimes even if there is delay of 0.5 sec causes End of speech.

Answer (score 0):

End of speech is expected to be raised after 0.5 seconds of silence. It is important to provide fast response in interactive applications. If you do not want to process it, you can ignore it and continue recognition.

Comment: Thanks Nikolay.. I am new to this.. please tell me how to ignore invoking of Endofspeech method or we can delay its call by few seconds.